# VBA To Filter Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which was running for the past number of weeks. The macro started failing. I added some with end withs to the code and solved the initial problem.
My code is now producing a "Syntax Error". Is there something I need to change in the with ?

Code

```
Sheets("Graph Worksheet").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Those first two `With...End with` do nothing and you should take then out.  Then if you still get an error it's useful to mention on which line and what the exact error message is.

Comment: That line was actually throwing an error originally, and the with end with sorted it. It's now the next line that is causing it.

Comment: "That line"  - which line and what error was it giving?  Helps to be as *specific* as you can.

Comment: Error occurring on With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal End With

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Microsoft for `With.. End With`:

> Executes a series of statements that repeatedly refer to a single object or structure so that the statements can use a simplified syntax when accessing members of the object or structure. When using a structure, you can only read the values of members or invoke methods, and you get an error if you try to assign values to members of a structure used in a With...End With statement.

Also:

> objectExpression   Required. An expression that evaluates to an object. The expression may be arbitrarily complex and is evaluated only once. The expression can evaluate to any data type, including elementary types.

In your example, the first 2 `With.. End With` are not needed at all, and can be omitted.

You also do not need to use `.Select` and should refrain from using this.

See below code:

```vb
Sub helper()

Sheets("Graph Worksheet").Rows("1:1").AutoFilter

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

As you will see the above compiles, but I have not tested it's use.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an error on line ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: See here for further information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add2

Comment: Thanks Dean, Unfortunately I don't see how that allows me to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using below code

```
Sheets("Graph Worksheet").Rows("1:1").AutoFilter

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
```